# Does Netty have support for Java 7 NIO 2 multicast?

Tags: nio, multicast, java-7, netty

What is the state of Netty Java 7 NIO 2 multicast support?

Does the current Netty release support multicast NIO instead of OIO-only as it was in java 6?

http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/oio/OioDatagramChannel.html

if not, what is the way to get this supported?

Answer (score 1):

As we still only require java6 for netty (even master) I don't think there is anything in there.. The only exception we have is the support for scpt but this is in a seperate module.

Comment: any time frame on java 7 multicast support?

Comment: No time frame yet, but contributions are welcome ;) I just added a issue to our tracker so we don't miss it. See https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/216

Comment: thank you for considering this; I'll see what I can contribute